# Install Dropbox client version for Linux Debian wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, dropbox

I try to searching the .deb pkg for amd64 to install the Dropbox client version, but I didn't find it. I also try to put in source.list more repositories and try to the official page of Dropbox, but it seems that the only package is this:

> Blockquote
>   nautilus-dropbox_0.7.1_amd64

I don't want to install nautilus because I have openbox in my debian wheezy and I hate nautilus.

Any suggests?

Comment: I've got an openbox debian setup and dropbox installed (came by default in #!), but I don't have that computer in front of me. If you don't have an answer by the time I get home, I'll figure out what's up with it and put something up for you.

Comment: OK, i solved with this:

64-bit:
cd ~ && wget -O - http://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64 | tar xzf -
        
Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist folder.

~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd

Comment: Don't forget to add it to your autostart.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.dropbox.com/install

> Install Dropbox via command line
>   The Dropbox daemon works fine on all 32-bit and 64-bit Linux servers. To install, run the following command in your Linux terminal.

32-bit:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - http://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86 | tar xzf -
```

64-bit:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - http://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64 | tar xzf -
```

Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist folder.

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

If you're running Dropbox on your server for the first time, you'll be asked to copy and paste a link in a working browser to create a new account or add your server to an existing account. Once you do, your Dropbox folder will be created in your home directory. Download this CLI script to control Dropbox from the command line. For easy access, put a symlink to the script anywhere in your PATH.